# How to refactor code duplicated in three classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, refactoring, code-duplication

In Visual Studio I have a ASP.NET 4.5 project, the language is C#. In that project I have found three classes (.cs) where most of the codes are the same, including fields and properties.

In such a case, what is a good approach to minimize and integrate (refactor) the duplicate code?

Comment: It's not uncommon for classes to share variable names. But if they are the same lines of code, maybe you should be looking into a base class(if it makes sense).

Comment: this is an obvious question, if you are duplicating code which means code reuse` then why not create a custom class and access the functionality from `1` place vs `3` different places.. are you familiar with the term code refactoring

Comment: I was thinking of creating a global class for variables, but I'm sure that there is better and professional way to implement. I'm looking for it.

Comment: "integerating same code lines" basically means refactoring. I've mentioned refactoring, as has @MethodMan and also@MyCodeSucks, though not directly. Please study up on refactoring before doing any "integration" of same code lines. Especially given your mention of a "global" class and the fact that this is an asp.net code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a risky refactoring process, but:

- you may want to start by writing unit tests if you don't have any
- pick one of the classes as the master
- rename the other ones to cause compiler errors
- rename the classes in the client code to the master class name
- recompile
- add in stuff from the other two classes into the master that isn't there already
- delete the two non-master classes

If you have ReSharper (or some other quality refactoring tools) available this process will go more smoothly.

Word of caution though... If you do not have unit tests set up it will be difficult to ensure that the code that looks duplicated actually is. It's easy to miss changes in logic just by visual inspection.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a global class for variables, but I'm sure that there is better and professional way to implement. I'm looking for it.

Comment: @Jay The **better and professional way** is to use: unit tests to make sure your code works as expected, static code analysis tools (identify duplicate code) and refactoring tools such as Resharper (modify code for the better). And if by global class you mean static then you could get into a world of hurt on a web farm. Please research these ideas: unit testing, static code analysis, refactoring, best practices, patterns

Comment: thank you for the response. I'm not really expert in ASP.net and I was thinking of the concept of including in PHP or importing in CSS. I think you know much professional thing, but this is not my state for now. Thank you again.

Comment: @Jay, you're welcome. The way to become a pro is to study and practice the ideas that are listed in the answer and comments. Good luck in your career!